# Jquery mobile example not working in browser

Tags: browser, jquery-mobile

I have created an example of jquery mobile which is completely working properly in jsfiddle.net but it's not working at all in any of the browser. i m providing the related links where you can test both in browser and jsfiddle.

```
 note:jsfiddle.net is the site where you can run and test the jquery examples.

    for brower :   http://errortec.blogspot.in/    

    u can copy the code from the errortec.blogspot.in and place it in your html file and check it in ur browser so that u can understand the problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In this case try to keep the javascript in on windows.load() as shown below :

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){

            $('#prevchild').click(function() {

                    $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), {
                    transition: 'slide',
                    reverse: true
                });
            });

            $('#nextchild').click(function() {

                $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), {
                    transition: 'slide',
                    reverse: true
                });
            });

            $('#login').click(function() {
                $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), {
                    transition: 'slide',
                    reverse: true
                });
            });

            $('#back').click(function() {
                $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), {
                    transition: 'slide',
                    reverse: true
                });
            });

            $('#next').click(function() {
                $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), {
                    transition: 'slide',
                    reverse: true
                });
            });

            $('#prev').click(function() {
                $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), {
                    transition: 'slide',
                    reverse: true
                });
            });
}
```

the body component is loaded after the script is executed & by using onload() script will execute after the component is loaded it so component will be aware of the script
i tried it and was helpfull to me ; i hope some one facing same problem will find it help full.

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing your script in a ready function:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
//your script here
});
```

There is also a spelling mistake the text attribute of your script tag is text/javacsript.
The navigation should also work if you simply use href attributes for your links.
For jquery mobile, some specific events are available: pageinit, pagecreate, pageshow.

Update: your click handlers should be added in the jQuery *ready* handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#prevchild').click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    });

    $('#nextchild').click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    });
    $('#login').click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    });
    $('#back').click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    });

    $('#next').click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried your code in Chrome and it works with this small change.

Comment: i dont understand ur answer above                                                          0 down vote accept
 

Try enclosing your script in a ready function:

$(document).ready( function() {
//your script here
});
and i'll check for spelling mistake

Comment: logically ur answer is right ,but in this case it's not working

Answer (score 0):

There is no start tag for your body. It should start between the last script tag and the first div.